# How can I get radio button value and upload it into firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

In this code, I want to upload the radio button value and store it in firebase database.I want use the simplest way to solve that. I see other code will use constructor but I do not know whether I can use simpler way to solve it. how can I do that ?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";
import Array from "../Array";

import firebase from "firebase";

export default () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="video">
        <ReactPlayer url={Array[0]} playing />
      </div>
      <label>Guess whether this video is fake or real ?</label> <br />
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="answer"
          value="real"
          onChange={e => setSelected(e.target.value)}
        />
        real
      </label>
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="answer"
          value="fake"
          onChange={e => setSelected(e.target.value)}
        />
        fake
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
import React from "react";
....
export default () => {
const [state, setState] = React.useState({});

const handleInputChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    console.log(name, value);
    setState(state => {
        const newState = { ...state, [name]: value }

        //post newState to firebase

       return newState
    });

};

return (
    <div>
        <div className="video">
            <ReactPlayer url={Array[0]} playing />
        </div>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(state)}</div>
        <label>Guess whether this video is fake or real ?</label> <br />
        <label>
            <input
                type="radio"
                name="answer1"
                value="real"
                onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
            real
        </label>
        <label>
            <input
                type="radio"
                name="answer2"
                value="fake"
                onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
            fake
        </label>
    </div>
);
```

};